# GNU readline-like library also tracking program state

Tags: library, c++, c

I need (want) some library for handling user input. I know GNU Readline can be user for this quite simply, but my issue is, that I want something that will track program state and manage transitions between states based on user input. Imagine classical gnupg "gui" for managing keys, or fdisk.

I would like to just define possible states in my program (probably using callbacks or something) and let library handle transitions and keeping track where we currently are.

Does anything like this exists? I didn't actually find anything for this.

EDIT: oh, and I need support for both linux and windows